Remove warning line number from Matlab exception.stack printout
I'm developing a try-catch structure for my Matlab R2020b program to manage exceptions. I want to print any exception messages, along with the line number, as warnings to the command window. My code is shown below:
%% try catch mockup

try
    print("Hey, that's not a valid command!") %this is bad syntax
catch exception
    line_number = string(exception.stack(length(exception.stack)).('line'));
    warning("Line " + line_number + " gave exception '" + string(exception.message) + "'");
end
disp("Now the code will finish")      

This displays the orange warning text
Warning: Line 4 gave exception 'No figure to print.' 
> In my_code_file (line 7) 

Line 4 is the correct line number for my exception. But I think that having the (line 7) statement, showing the line number for the warning, is distracting and could confuse my fellow developers/users about which line number is relevant. Is there a way to remove that part of the exception printout?

Honestly, this is not a real problem, is it?  Any developer who has encountered exceptions would be able to figure out the situation from that traceback.  The users can adjust whether this appears using the warning settings: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/warning.html

Thank you for referencing those settings. Also, for future readers - I am changing my syntax to warning(getReport(exception,'extended')) for a more-detailed exception printout.

This will do it, but if your code is in a library or module, remember that those settings really belong to the application writer.  You shouldn't mess with them.

Don’t catch exceptions unless you can solve the problem (eg retry with a different parameter or whatever). If the code has an unexpected error, it needs to stop ASAP so the error can be fixed. Continuing after an error is just going to lead to more errors or subtly wrong output.

@CrisLuengo yes, I agree that's part of the zen of Python, "Errors should never pass silently."
